# How can I force the Unity launcher to start programs in a window which is not maximised

Tags: unity, compiz, launcher, window

Bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/704187/ means Wine programs can not be run maximised because there is a mouse displacement. Unity usually seems to start programs maximised. So is there any command line I can put in the Unity launcher file (.desktop file) or any other way to ensure the program is not started maximised and preferably specify the starting window size/position or that it is the same as when it was last used?

Answer (score 0):

If the main purpose is for wine, this doesn't answer the application un-maximized in unity question, but you can tell wine to run applications in a virtual desktop to avoid that issue with wine. Just run winecfg, and under the Graphics tab select emulate a virtual desktop.

Comment: It does not seem to make any difference when I launch the programs from Unity even after a logout.

Comment: I'm sorry, It was just a thought... >_<. I don't like unity very much, and usually select a basic gnome desktop when I go to login, >_<. Good luck, though!